# how to develop radio application for iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

just wanted to know how to develop radio application for iphone is any third party providers are required for the radio station services what are the API's available in iphone SDk please suggest how to start with.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way I suggest you to do is to

1.Create an instance of UIWebView and then add it as a subview to your parent view.
2.Use the loadRequest method on WebView object , and load the url of the radio station.

ex.

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://radiostationURL"]]];
```

Thanks